# AngularJS - HTML data binding UI issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am binding following in my HTML.

```
<div>{{user.address[0].addressline1}}, {{user.address[0].addressline2}}, {{user.address[0].city}}, {{user.address[0].state}}, {{user.address[0].zipcode}}</div>
```

The issue is if `addressline1` is `null`, it unnecessarily shows the `,` at first.

And also some other fields can be `null`

So How to display comma only if the value is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or as a matter of style, you can use a turnery operator to check for the value then format it

```
{{ !!user.address[0].addressline1 ? user.address[0].addressline1 + ', ' : ''}}
```

This could be made as filter to be more intuitive

```
angular.module('myapp', []).filter('trailIfTrue', [function(){
     return function(val, trail){
         return !!val ? val + trail : '';
     }
}]);
```

usage:

```
{{ user.address[0].addressline1 | trailIfTrue:',' }}
```

[here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MTimRpDRd26XozpI6e7a?p=preview)

Comment: I liked the `filter` option & used it...As it can be reused if i need it later...! Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

User separate `span` and [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) so the span will be shown only if `user.address[0].addressline1` is not null

```
<span ng-show="user.address[0].addressline1">{{user.address[0].addressline1}},</span>
<span ng-show="user.address[0].addressline2">{{user.address[0]. addressline2}},</span>
<span ng-show="user.address[0].city">{{user.address[0].city}},</span>
//...
```

You can use any expression into `ng-show` Eg:

```
user.address[0].addressline1 != null
myObj.myIntAttr > 0 && < 10
myObj.myBoolAttr == false
//...
```